# como cargar JcomboBox con datos de una tabla?

Tags: java, mysql-workbench

necesito  cargar un combobox con el id_auto de la tabla automóvil y hasta ahora no encuentro como hacerlo.
lo que hice fue insetar valores por defecto 
pero quiero hacer una consulta a la base de datos para que me traiga los valores agregados desde otro formulario a esa tabla.
.
..
.

```
public void insertarConductor(){
    try {
        String SQL = "insert into conductor (documento, nombre, apellido, licencia, fecha_nacimiento, telefono, direccion, correo, fk_idauto)"
                + " values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        pst.setString(1, txtDocumento.getText());
        pst.setString(2, txtNombre.getText());
        pst.setString(3, txtApellido.getText());
        pst.setString(4, txtLicencia.getText());
        pst.setString(5, ((JTextField)FechaNacimientoCond.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
        pst.setString(6, txtTelefono.getText());
        pst.setString(7, txtDireccion.getText());
        pst.setString(8, txtCorreo.getText());

        int seleccionado = numeroAuto.getSelectedIndex();
        pst.setString(9, numeroAuto.getItemAt(seleccionado));

        pst.execute();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registro exitoso");
        this.dispose();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error de Registro"+ e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero se crea una clase de `Auto`, esta tiene que contener todos los atributos que contiene la tabla del mismo nombre en la base de datos.

Posteriormente debes de realizar un listado, de todos los registros que tienes en la base de datos

```java
// se crea una variable tipo arrayList de auto
private static ArrayList<Auto> alAuto = new ArrayList<Auto>();

public ArrayList<Auto> listarAutos() throws Exception{
        //Abre la base de datos
        con = conexion.conectar("bbdd");
        try{
            //Crea un statement para que la base de datos se 
            //prepare para recibir una query
            st = con.createStatement();
            //se crea una query para sacar todo lo que contiene la tabla auto
            query = "SELECT * FROM autos ORDER BY Id_estado ASC";
            //se ejecuta la query y se envía el resultado a rs
            rs = st.executeQuery(query);
            //se crean variables para poder recibir lo de rs y 
            //otorgarlo al ArrayList de tipo auto
            //Aquí deberían ir todos los atributos que tiene la tabla,
            // con el mismo tipo de dato
            int idAuto;
            String Marca;
            //se limpia todo el ArrayList al Auto, ya que si 
            //llamas al método dos veces y no limpias,se duplican los datos
            alAuto.removeAll(alAuto);
            //se crea un while que funcione mientras rs traiga otro dato
            while(rs.next()){
                //Se guarda lo que trae rs (atributos de la tabla)
                // en la variable anteriormente creada
                idAuto = rs.getInt("Id_auto");
                marca = rs.getString("marca");
                //Rellena el array creando una instancia de estado con los
                // datos recibidos por las variables anteriores
                alAuto.add(new Estado(idAuto, marca)); 
            }        
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqle);
        }
        //cierra la base de datos y retorna arrayList alAuto
        con.close();
        return alAuto;
}
```

---

Teniendo lo anterior ahora, se puede agregar todo al `comboBox`, en este caso solo voy a agregar `marca`, lo haré mediante un método que se llamará `rellenarComboAutos()`:

```java
//Recibe el combo que deseas rellenar
public void rellenarComboAutos (JComboBox cbxAutos) throws Exception{
       //para limpiar combobox de item por defecto
        cbxAutos.removeAllItems();

        //Rellena el comboBox con la descripción del ArrayList alAutos
        for(int i = 0; i < listarAutos().size() ; i++ ){
            cbxAutos.addItem(listarAutos().get(i).getMarca());
        }
        //Item seleccionado por defecto, en la posición 0
        cbxAuto.setSelectedIndex(0);
    }
```